# What is the latest date for the setting in a sci-fi text or movie?

Tags: science-fiction-genre, origins, timeline

I was thinking of the Mayans this morning, and the controversy about the Mayan calendar in 2012 (through a long and circuitous thought process). But it got me thinking: Someone back 5000 years ago built a calendar which planned ahead 5000 years.

Lots of sci-fi books, stories, and movies are based in the future, and many of them have specific dates - Star Trek is mostly in the 23rd and 24th centuries, for instance.

This got me thinking... what is the latest date ever for the setting of a sci-fi story? I'm specifically ruling out time travel, unless a specific date is given. Vague 'millions of years in the future' like in H.G. Wells' *Time Machine* or a similar PK Dick story aren't really what I'm looking for, so they aren't relevant. May consider time travelers from the future if a specific date of their source is given (i.e. no "I'm from the 31st century, hello!" - not specific enough).

I'd consider just a year, or even maybe a small range of years, close enough, but no more vague than that.

Comment: Actually, *The Time Machine* takes place in the year AD 802,701.

Comment: You rule out 90% of all sf stories, because there are very much Settings where the exact date of our calendar is deliberately obfuscated or simply not given. Star Wars takes place "a Long time ago". Dune and many others have their own calendar. Even Star Trek (Tos) had its own calendar and was adjusted later to ours.

Comment: Rogue Jedi - thanks... I hadn't read the time machine in a while, i forgot there was an exact date. Hothie - that's intentional, i'm not sure if the mayans actually wrote down their date equivalent to 2012, but i was looking for writings with specific dates.

Comment: The final episode of the fourth season of Babylon 5 has a flash forward to the year [AD 1,002,262](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Deconstruction_of_Falling_Stars), although this pales in comparison to some of the answers below.

Comment: @RogueJedi The Time Machine also mentions travelling to the end of the universe. Remember the crabs?

Comment: Why "5000 years" for the Mayan calendar. It has units at approximately 1, 20, 394, 7885, 157704, 3154071 & 63081429 years, but none at 5000.

Comment: don't really know... from a quick reference, the mayans were ~3200bc or so, and people said their calendar ended in 2012. i could be wrong.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman The Mayan "calendar" works in cycles; 2012 was just the ending of the cycle before it began again.

Comment: ITT: OP has to keep reminding people he wants an "exact date".  Not a calculated one, not an approximate one, an exactly sequence of digits that appears in science fiction.

Comment: "Tau Zero" goes fairly far as well.

Comment: Was going to mention Azimov's *The End of Eternity*, but I read it decades ago and can't remember if it specifies a future "latest date" or not.  Its Wikipedia entry doesn't mention one.

Comment: The events in _Dune_ take place in the year 10191 AG. It may be noteworthy that AG means "After Guild" though, the establishment of the Spacing Guild. I'm not sure if there's any canon confirmation of which Earth year this is. (Only counting the books by Frank Herbert as canon.)

Comment: Are you counting instances where the characters are "traveling into the future" in a continuous way (rather than jumping instantaneously from one time to another), and they mention passing through certain milestones as they travel, or are you only interested in cases where they actually "stop" in a particular year and experience time at the normal rate, or cases where no time travel is involved?

Comment: Well, what I ended up asking for were specific date references... so that would have to be where they stop in an particular year (not 'a year 10000 years in the future', but 'in year 10351'). passing references i might consider, but isn't my intention. honestly, i should have just removed time travel as an option altogether - was really hoping for the setting of a story or episode - but that is what i asked for, and got lots of good answers, so i'll keep it as is.

Comment: The last Mayan was killed by the Spain in 1697 so their calender forecasts roughly 500 years and not 5000. Plus they didn't predicted the end of the world but rather the end of their current calendar. Current civilization doesn't predict the end of the world at the 31.12.2015 just because our calendar ends there. Neither does Micosoft predict the end at the year 2099

Comment: @JonasDralle, but the world did end in Y2K

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the exact amount of time, but I believe the book [Diaspora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaspora_(novel)) deserves a mention. Based on the description of what happens at the end of the book (no spoilers) it *must* be an extremely long time.  There might be enough info in the book to calculate it.

Comment: if it has to be calculated, it's not relevant imho. sorry...

Comment: It bothers me a bit that somehow the Restaurant at the End of the Universe doesn't count.

Comment: The finale of Isaac Asimov's short story [The Last Question](http://imgur.com/gallery/9KWrH) takes place some immeasurable amount of time after the final heat death of the universe.

Comment: @Kevin Workman _..also mentions travelling to the end of the universe._ Actually, the end of our **sun** (solar system), not _the universe_. However it really takes place much later than 802,701 (the main setting year).

Comment: To what level of precision does the text need to give the date for you to consider it to be a date? If you want it to the nearest femtosecond, then there's almost certainly nothing at all. If you want it to the nearest hundred trillion years, then the field is wide open. I expect you want something in between -- but exactly _where_ in between? Nearest century? Nearest year? Nearest day? Nearest hour?

Comment: as i wrote in the question, i'd consider a specific year, or a small range of years, close enough.

Comment: I'll take this chance to mention Greg Bear's *City at the End of Time*. Much of the story takes place in an epoch when the heat death of the universe is in the ancient past.

Comment: Your criteria are too vague and subjective--even with your "small range of years" requirement, you still think the Doctor Who "five billion and fifty-three" answer is too "hand-wavy." -1.

Comment: yeah, i know.... but it's my question :)

Comment: If you can figure out when the "temporal point of departure" occurred in [Iron Ladies, Iron Tigers](http://clarkesworldmagazine.com/moraine_07_12/), then you only have to add 10^1500 years to find out when the story takes place.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I'm not sure how specific of a date you're looking for, but ["Utopia"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utopia_(Doctor_Who)), an episode of the third season of the revived *Doctor Who*, takes place in the year 100 trillion:

> **Doctor:**  We're accelerating into the future. The year one billion. Five billion. Five trillion. Fifty trillion? What? The year one hundred trillion? That's impossible.
>
> <sup><sub>[*Doctor Who* Series 3 Episode 11: "Utopia"](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/29-11.htm)</sub></sup>

Although that seems vague (and it doesn't really have a lot of significant figures), I'm inclined to take his word for it they they really did land in exactly the year 100 trillion; the Doctor really is the sort of character who'd tell us the precise year, even if he'd landed in the year 186,165,555,852,002.

But if that's still too vague, another *Doctor Who*; ["Gridlock"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gridlock_(Doctor_Who)) takes place in the year 5 billion and fifty-three:

> **Doctor:** I don't want to go home. Instead, this is much better. Year five billion and fifty-three, planet New Earth. Second hope of mankind. Fifty thousand light years from your old world, and we're slap bang in the middle of New New York. Although, technically it's the fifteenth New York from the original, so it's New New New New New New New New New New New New New New York. One of the most dazzling cities ever built.
>
> <sup><sub>[*Doctor Who* Series 3 Episode 2: "Gridlock"](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/29-3.htm)</sub></sup>

Comment: There's also an episode of *Red Dwarf* that takes place so far beyond the end of the Universe that time has looped back around to 1993; anyone who wants to do the math to figure out how far in the future that is, is welcome to pinch that as an answer

Comment: No thank you. I remember a novel though, a serious novel even, that uses the same concept. A man travels forward in time, desperately needs to travel back, can't, needs to go forward an eternity to get back to the beginning. If only I could remember which novel. I feel another question coming on.

Comment: @MrLister That sounds familiar to me too, actually...

Comment: @MrLister there was an episode of Futurama with that exact premise - probably inspired by that story

Comment: well, i'm not looking for number of years, but a date, so circling through the history of the universe isn't relevant. but 5,000,000,023 sounds pretty specific, as an exact date.

Comment: hmm, should ask... that's probably a british billion, which would make it 5,000,000,000,023 i think.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman I have it on good authority (Richard, an actual Englishman) that nobody in England uses the long billion anymore; so knock three zeroes out of the middle of that

Comment: @CorleyBrigman Actually, make that 5 billion and **fifty**-three; there's a later episode that goes to the same planet thirty years later

Comment: I'm going to accept this one... it still feels a bit hand-wavy but it _is_ a very specific year, and all the larger ones feel too vague to me.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman it's not hand-wavy, it's timey wimey ;)

Comment: Even if the year one hundred trillion isn't exact, that episode still takes place just before the heat death of the universe; I'm pretty sure that is as far in the future as it's possible to get :)

Comment: @JasonBaker, I was just thinking, I'm British but I've never heard of this "British billion".

Comment: @PointlessSpike that is because in Britain it is just called a billion!

Comment: @JamesRyan, No it's not. To Brits a billion is 1,000,000,000. This might help explain it: http://www.plainenglish.co.uk/campaigning/past-campaigns/budget/how-much-is-a-billion.html

Comment: @PointlessSpike I am British, I know what both a real billion and an American billion are. :)

Comment: @JamesRyan, We'll have to agree to disagree, but I suspect you'll end up confusing people.

Comment: Any reference to "New New New New New New New New New New New New New New York" always gets a +1 in my book.  Even if the answer is terrible. (This one isn't, by the way.)

Answer (score 89):

In the Futurama episode "The Late Philip J Fry" they travel forward in time to the heat-death of the universe, and even further until a new Big Bang spontaneously occurs and they loop back to the year they started from.

**Twice.**

<strike>[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe), the estimated time frame for quantum fluctuations to create a new universe is 10^10^56, so we can estimate that they travelled 2 x 10^10^56 years into the future.</strike>
**Read below for why this is very probably not true.***

To give an exact date: They traveled to the year 3010, two universes into the future.

EDIT: To answer some questions from the comments, the oldest mentioned year from the episode is 1x10^40 AD.

[image: oldest date in episode]

Since they are traveling through time, and the time machine is counting the exponents, they were definitely exactly in the year 10^40, even if only for a split second of their time.

*As for the estimate of 10^10^56 being the last year they are at due to the idea that quantum fluctuations caused the new Big Bang is just speculation due to the cause of the new Big Bang not being specified. However: Going frame by frame through the video as the year counter is ticking, the time machine is ticking through time exponentially at a constant rate of 10 frames per +1 exponent. The time machine seems to be going faster the longer it runs, at least in the old universe, and counting the amount of frames between the frame it counts 1x10^40 to the frame the new Big Bang happens (336 frames afterwards), the best estimate we can get to the farthest they got into the future is around 10^(40 + 33.6) or 10^77.6, which would make way more sense given the speed they were shown to be traveling. If this is even in the ballpark of true, then even if they continued at their exponential acceleration they would have to spend *longer in the time machine than the universe took to die* to reach the year 10^10^56.

Man, exponents are cray-cray.

Comment: Not concerned with number of years, but the date. I'll count 3010 though.

Comment: In that case, the universe ends at 10^40 AD in that episode, so that can be considered the latest date.

Written out: 100,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000.

Of course, 10^40 gives a pretty broad scope as to the exact year, but it's the date given by the time machine they're flying in.

Comment: “and even further”—so they ruled out even the [Restaurant at the End of the Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Restaurant_at_the_End_of_the_Universe)…

Comment: @RSmith What is the latest date shown on the controls of the time machine in the episode?

Comment: You should qualify that statement about the "estimated time frame for quantum fluctuations to create a new universe"--that figure is based on [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0410270), but it's only an estimate for the time frame in one particular cosmological model, the [eternal inflation](http://scienceblogs.com/startswithabang/2011/10/28/why-we-think-theres-a-multiver/) model where new universes spontaneously inflate from tiny patches of old ones, and the previous universe doesn't actually "end" but just keeps expanding forever, so a time traveler in the old universe would have to

Comment: (cont) be at exactly the right place and time to experience a new Big Bang. I think the Futurama ep makes more sense in terms a [cyclic model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_model) of cosmology, in which the entire universe periodically experiences a new Big Bang.

Comment: @Hypnosifl That can't be true because the universes aren't identical. The first one is, but the second one is ten feet lower. Also, in the Big Crunch model, the universe never experiences heat death (it collapses before that), yet in the episode they watch the last proton decay.

Comment: @Xantec I'll provide a screenshot with the latest date shown later when I'm able to watch the episode again.

Comment: @RSmith - Cyclic models in physics don't require that each new cycle be identical to the last. Also, not all cyclic models involve a contraction of the universe into a Big Crunch (that model is actually considered unlikely nowadays because there doesn't seem any way to avoid the conclusion that entropy would increase each cycle) there is also a model in which our universe is a "brane" (a 3D membrane in a higher-dimensional space), and periodic Big Bangs are triggered by periodic collisions with another brane, see [this article](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/a-recycled-universe/).

Comment: @Hypnosifl Hmm then I'll have to check the episode again to make sure and maybe come up with a better estimate of just how far into the future they went. I'll come back to this later when I've watched the episode again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30829/discussion-between-rsmith-and-hypnosifl).

Comment: @Xantec - Various very large numbers are shown on the time machine control panel as they journey rapidly into the future (without stopping at any far-future dates beyond a billion years), we do see the control panel change from something times 10^39 years to something times 10^40 years, though the prefix numbers are a blur (but presumably they must have passed through exactly 1 x 10^40 years at the moment the exponent changed).

Comment: @Hypnosifl Wellon the part _"a time traveler in the old universe would have to be at exactly the right place and time to experience a new Big Bang"_ I totally must note, that - according to my knowledge - time/space could not exist without matter and energy, so at the exact moment of the Big Bang the universe is small enough to not let the traveller be really far from the cosmic egg.

Comment: @mg30rg - I was referring to what would be true in a specific model known as "eternal inflation", since the figure of 10^10^56 years that RSmith mentioned was from [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0410270) that was based on that model. In eternal inflation, the Big Bang is not really the beginning of space and time, rather there was a preexisting expanding universe, and a small patch of space in that earlier universe experienced a quantum fluctuation that caused it to suddenly inflate in size very rapidly, and that's what our Big Bang was (according to the model).

Answer (score 45):

**10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 AD**

Part of [Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold:_Time) by [Stephen Baxter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Baxter_%28author%29) is directly mentioned to take place **10 ^ 113th power years** into the future.  As the descendants of humanity try to survive the [heat-death of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe).  They succeed partly by becoming lossless computing algorithms.  Most of the matter in the universe has suffered [proton decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay), and even the [largest black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_massive_black_holes) have evaporated through [hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation).

[image: Manifold: Time]

Comment: is that an exact date? i'm specifically not looking for general 'xxx years into the future' type things.

Comment: While they don't mention the exact day of the year, they talk about the various orders of magnitude as they travel further into the future.  At this point a work is unlikely to mention an exact day of year because both our current time systems are probably out-dated by then and the order of magnitude is a far more relevant indicator of time.

Comment: Because of relativity and time-dilation, time keeping between solar systems is probably more complex.

Comment: And because after heat death there is no free energy, meaning nothing ever happens again. Time becomes literally impossible to measure if there are no events to measure between!

Comment: @MarkRogers Don't worry about relativity, one can theoretically use "vacuum" time, which is universally the "fastest" one to pass.

Comment: @Zommuter - The vacuum does not have its own rest frame in quantum field theory. The most common frame to use in cosmology is one in which the observers who are at rest in this frame are the ones who see the cosmic background radiation as approximately symmetrical in all directions, rather than being more redshifted in one direction and more blueshifted in the other direction.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Aw, right you are, I was only thinking of vacuum such as to avoid _general_ relativistic time effects, but due to the symmetry of the Doppler effect even your proposition may turn out impossible :/ However, a civilization can agree upon and convert to a specific beacon's time...

Answer (score 33):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned [The Last Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Question) by Isaac Asimov.

This short story traces humanity's evolution until it exists outside of space or time, after the heat death of the universe (10 trillion years in the future).

You can read it [here](http://www.physics.princeton.edu/ph115/LQ.pdf).

Comment: that's not an exact date... so too vague for the purposes of this answer. interesting though.

Comment: I came here looking for this answer and am surprised it second to last! This is so for sure the correct answer. It starts in 2061, and goes until the last energy dissipates out of the universe.

Comment: I thought of this too. If you hadn't provided it as an answer, I would've. Its not a specific date, but its about as far into the future as unhumanly possible.

Comment: This is an awesome story, never heard of it before. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 30):

I'm really surprised no one has listed the second Hitch Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy book, *The Restaurant at the End of the Universe*, the titular Restaurant sits in a shield bubble and rocks back and forth through time so that successive dinners can be held where the spectacle of the End of the Universe can be witnessed.

Comment: That's not a date, though... it seems like the asker is specifically excluding undated far-future periods.

Comment: @recognizer That may be best left as an exercise to the reader. :)

Comment: @recognizer: A date is just an identifiable point in time. The end of the universe is also an identifiable point in time. If you asked me what time I got to the office and I said, "At sunrise," would that be any different than "7:48 this morning"?

Comment: @Ellesedil That's a perfectly workable definition of a "date" when you're not writing an answer to a question that states "Vague 'millions of years in the future'... aren't really what I'm looking for, so they aren't relevant." The end of the universe is about the vaguest future date you can give.

Comment: @Ellesedil A bit of research shows that the master of ceremonies at Milliways describes the age of the universe, at its end, as "over one hundred and seventy thousand million billion years". That, compared with the current age of the universe, age of Earth, etc might provide the basis for an answer that actually fits the specificity the asker is looking for.

Comment: @recognizer I'd disagree, the end of the universe is a pretty specific date. It might be a little hard to determine on say the Gregorian calendar as it hasn't happened yet. However at the point where our Sun has gone nova, or the Earth has been destroyed to make way for a Hyperspace Bypass, the Gregorian calendar is pretty moot anyways.

Comment: I believe Marvin mentioned an exact number of years. Don't remember what it was though.

Comment: Even if you find the exact number of years for the end of the universe that Marvin mentions you still aren't done.  In "So Long, and Thanks for All the Fish" Marvin shows up again, within the same year, soon after earth is destroyed and rebuilt.  Having been left behind at the end of the universe, without benefit of time travel, he simply went around again.  37 times.

Answer (score 21):

Warhammer 40,000 takes place in the 41st millenium (who'd have guessed, right?). And it uses quite an elaborate dating and time tracking scheme, so there are a lot of exact dates involved. For example, the history of the [Siege of Vraks](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Siege_of_Vraks) involves mentions of years 40,804 (exact date 366**804.M41** in Imperial syntax), 40,809 or 40,813.

Comment: yeah, those are pretty exact... they definitely count, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I'll start bidding at 9595 from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N03Uoj6p9QA)

> In the year 2525 If man is still alive If woman can survive They may
>   find In the year 3535 Ain't gonna need to tell the truth, tell no lies
>   Everything you think, do, and say Is in the pill you took today
>
> In the year 4545 Ain't gonna need your teeth, won't need your eyes You
>   won't find a thing to chew Nobody's gonna look at you
>
> In the year 5555 Your arms are hanging limp at your sides Your legs
>   got nothing to do Some machine is doing that for you
>
> In the year 6565 Ain't gonna need no husband, won't need no wife
>   You'll pick your son, pick your daughter too From the bottom of a long
>   glass tube' Whoooa
>
> In the year 7510 If God's a-comin' he ought to make it by then Maybe
>   he'll look around himself and say Guess it's time for the Judgement
>   day
>
> In the year 8510 God is gonna shake his mighty head then He'll either
>   say I'm pleased where man has been Or tear it down and start again
>
> In the year 9595 I'm kinda wondering if man is gonna be alive He's
>   taken everything this old earth can give And he ain't put back nothing
>
> Now it's been 10, 000 years Man has cried a billion tears For what he
>   never knew Now man's reign is through But through eternal night The
>   twinkling of starlight So very far away Maybe it's only yesterday

Comment: that sounds a like a reference to 9595, but not a setting... anyways, there are larger numbers already.

Comment: That's a big quote without mentioning who wrote it.

Comment: So... Cleopatra 2525?

Comment: That's not a sci-fi text or movie.

Comment: It's a scifi song ;)

Answer (score 7):

According article in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_future_in_science_fiction_and_popular_culture):

> 10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000: In Frederick
>   Pohl's novel The World at the End of Time,

Answer (score 5):

*[Last and First Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_and_First_Men)*, written in 1930 by Olaf Stapledon, spans about 2 billion years. It describes the rise and fall of eighteen distinct "human" species, of which our own is the first.

Comment: If anyone is interested, you can read the book here: https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/s/stapledon/olaf/last/

Comment: And the plot of Last and First Men occupies a minor part of the time span of The Star Maker.

Answer (score 4):

Joe Haldeman's [The Accidental Time Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Accidental_Time_Machine).

In this story, a time machine that goes forward only is created.  Each use of it is 12x longer forward in time than the previous use (and some physical displacement too).  The artificial intelligence that controls LA (known as La) goes on a trip to the heat death of the universe.

I will concede that the specific times visited are:

2058
2059
2060
2074
2252
4346
+24,000
+320,000
+3.5 million

At this point, the main characters take a different path through time as La continues to the future. It is noted that La's goal of getting to the point where there is no energy will exist (at the heat death) will be forever impossible as La has enough energy for a very, very, very long time to keep pushing that button and going another 12x deeper into the future.

> “La. So you want to go all the way up.”
>   “That’s right. The heat death of the universe.”
>
> ...
>
> “Jesse nodded, looking at the space where the ship had been. “I’ve never tried to go so far up. I assume the thing will keep working, but asymptotically.”
>   “She’ll get closer and closer, but never quite be there?”
>   “As she must have known. As long as she can still push the button, the show isn’t over. By definition.”

Answer (score 4):

*The End of Eternity* by Isaac Asimov is a time travel story where the characters measure time in centuries. Although its future dates are nowhere close to some of the exponentially high examples in other answers, I think it's still worth noting as a work with non-rounded dates in the far future.

Some of the centuries visited in the novel are:

- 95th: Andrew Harlan's home century
- 482nd: century where Noÿs Lambent works
- 2456th: Socialist Voy's work place
- 111394th: a century where Noÿs hides (11,139,300-11,139,399 AD)

Answer (score 0):

Mike Harris answered with:

> Last and First Men, written in 1930 by Olaf Stapledon, spans about 2 billion years. It describes the rise and fall of eighteen distinct "human" species, of which our own is the first.

And I add that Stapledon wrote a sort of a sequel describing the history of the entire universe *The star Maker* (1937) that extends farther into the future.