# What is the most distant future time period in science fiction?

Tags: time-travel, time

Parameters:
0. It must be a *finite* time period from the beginning of the Universe, (like 1 billion years)
1. It must have some relevance to the story or plot
2. It cannot be open ended, 'end of the Universe' as in [The Last Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Question)
3. Any Universe is allowed provided that it has a beginning (like a [Big Bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang))

Comment: Clicked wrong VTC reason.  Duplicate of [What is the latest date for the setting in a sci-fi text or movie?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106203/what-is-the-latest-date-for-the-setting-in-a-sci-fi-text-or-movie/106207#106207)

Comment: Also, one billion years from the beginning of the universe is about 13 billion years ago.  That is the opposite of the distant future.

Comment: @WadCheber You are right, I didn't see that.

Comment: The Doctor, Jack Harkness, and Martha Jones travel to the year 100 trillion in the Doctor Who episode `Utopia`

Comment: Professor Farnsworth, Fry, and Bender travel to the very last moment of the universe 3 times in the Futurama episode `The Late Philip J. Fry`

Comment: I'm not good with the math's but Asimov's Foundation is surely in the running.

Comment: I'd have to check if specific years are mentioned but Stephen Baxter's 'Time' and Frederik Pohl's 'The World at the End of Time' both handle the universe's heat death, so they could qualify.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's in Stephen Baxter's **[Manifold: Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold:_Time)**

Sheena – a genetically engineered squid, is traveling into the very deep future.
Paperback edition page 222

> Malenfant said, "So the asteroid just evaporated."
>   "Yes, it got smaller and smaller, warmed gently by the annihilation of electrons and positrons in its interior, a thin smoke of neutrinos drifting out at light speed."
>   Emma asked, "How long this time?"
>   "The theories are sketchy, if you want me to put a number on it, I'd say **ten to a power one hundred seventeen years**." Even Cornelius looked bewildered now.

<sup>Bold added</sup>

[Mr. Baxter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Baxter_(author))'s (an astrophysicist) idea is akin to [Timeline of the far future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_far_future)

[image: Far future]